# Grab second tuple in Python list

Tags: python, list, parsing, unicode, tuples

I'm trying to grab the second item of a list within a list in Python..

Example:

`people = [['John Doe', u'', u'25.78', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.39', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'11.93', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'14.97', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'14.34', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'21.08', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.24', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.11', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'19.45', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.56', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'20.57', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'28.50', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'24.38', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'31.13', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.20', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'18.52', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'6.42', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.31', u'']]`

What I'm trying to do is grab the third element of each list within the list.

I want my return to be:

`['25.78','13.39','11.93','14.97','14.34']` and so on.

Also, bonus points. Will the `u` in the front of each item in the list affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [each[2] for each in people]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [57]: people = [['John Doe', u'', u'25.78', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.39', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'11.93', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'14.97', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'14.34', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'21.08', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.24', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'13.11', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'19.45', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.56', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'20.57', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'28.50', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'24.38', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'31.13', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.20', u''], ['John Doe', u'', u'18.52', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'6.42', u'0.00'], ['John Doe', u'', u'17.31', u'']]

In [58]: [p[2] for p in people]
Out[58]: 
[u'25.78',
 u'13.39',
 u'11.93',
 u'14.97',
 u'14.34',
 u'21.08',
 u'13.24',
 u'13.11',
 u'',
 u'19.45',
 u'17.56',
 u'20.57',
 u'28.50',
 u'24.38',
 u'31.13',
 u'17.20',
 u'18.52',
 u'6.42',
 u'17.31']
```

The `u` in front of your strings basically says that they are unicode strings. If you want to cast them into regular ascii strings (assuming they have only ascii characters):

```
In [59]: [str(p[2]) for p in people]
Out[59]: 
['25.78',
 '13.39',
 '11.93',
 '14.97',
 '14.34',
 '21.08',
 '13.24',
 '13.11',
 '',
 '19.45',
 '17.56',
 '20.57',
 '28.50',
 '24.38',
 '31.13',
 '17.20',
 '18.52',
 '6.42',
 '17.31']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension to get the third element.

```
numbers = [i[2] for i in people]
```

The `u` indicates that it is a unicode string. Assuming it contains `ascii` characters (which in this case it does) you can just use `str` if you don't want unicode.

```
numbers = [str(i[2]) for i in people]
```

Answer (score 0):

and here it is as numpy

```
people = numpy.array(people)
print people[:,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, just for fun:

```
result = []
for x in range(len(people)):
    result.append(people[x][2])
```

Comment: @wim It may not be the smart or Pythonic way to do it, but it works.